# CMake error: Failed to run MSBuild command to get the value of VCTargetsPath

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, cmake

I am encountering an error while attempting to generate build files for my project with CMake. The error message reads as follows:

`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project): Failed to run MSBuild command to get the value of VCTargetsPath: The system cannot find the file specified.`

I have verified that `MSBuild.exe` is accessible and added to the `PATH` environment variable after installing the Microsoft Build Tools. Despite having done this, I am still unable to resolve the issue. I have also attempted restarting both the IDE and the command prompt to ensure that the changes take effect.

My environment comprises:

- VS Code version 1.78.2
- CMake version 3.14

I would appreciate any suggestions or insights into how to successfully generate build files for the project with CMake.

Comment: did you run VS Code from the corresponding visual studio developer prompt?